# Pinned OneDrive taskbar icon opens in File Explorer instead (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar

I am able to pin OneDrive to the taskbar by clicking "Pin to taskbar".

However, when I click the icon, a separate File Explorer icon opens in the OneDrive folder instead.

This seems unnecessary. Is there a way to pin OneDrive to the taskbar and have it open in its own icon?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try unpinning it and pinning it again. Sometimes, this happens and you have to re-pin it to the taskbar. You might also considering using another user account to test it or restarting your computer.